# Silicone caulk turned yellow within 24 hours

Tags: bathroom, tile, caulking, silicone

I caulked in my new shower and around my tub with [GE Advanced silicone caulk](https://gesealants.com/products/advanced-silicone-2-kitchen-bath-sealant/2708925) and within 24 hours it turned yellow. Yellow around wall tile in shower and the apron of the tub. Everything in the bathroom is white so no leaching from anything brown. Complete gut, no mold, mildew or water damage. Room is a bit humid

Comment: Maybe you need to specify what product you used and perhaps a photo might help.

Comment: [GE Advanced](https://gesealants.com/products/advanced-silicone-2-kitchen-bath-sealant/2708925) is apparently available in only three colors. Which is yours?

Comment: I got GE advanced white silicone. I’ll add a picture below if it lets me

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I wonder if it’s something that it releases as it dries, because I was able to wash the yellow away with water and rubbing it with my fingers.

Comment: No. Brand new silicone bought from Lowe’s and put on a white tub with a white shower enclosure and the next day it was turning yellow after the water hit it for the first time. even had yellow puddles of water coming from it the following day.
It has not been expired. Expiration date December 2024.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two reasons:

1. You used an expired product, so check the expiration date.
2. You bought colored sealant

Comment: Or the surroundings are tinted blue, and the white just looks yellow by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

> I caulked in my new shower and around my tub with GE Advanced silicone caulk and within 24 hours it turned yellow. Yellow around wall tile in shower and the apron of the tub. Everything in the bathroom is white so no leaching from anything brown. Complete gut, no mold, mildew or water damage. Room is a bit humid

given your post was a statement, i will assume the underlying question is why and what to do next.  I would google `reasons for silicone turning yellow`.

> *humidity counts as chemical exposure*

> good news is that this yellowing is temporary and it can be removed with normal household cleaning products, simply spraying some household bleach onto the silicone and allowing it to sit for 10-15 minutes before rinsing it off will get rid of the yellow color.

https://www.bostik.com/australia/en_AU/bostik-academy/library/yellow-silicone/

> Some silicones, especially in construction sites, have showed a tendency to turn yellow even before the job has been handed over to the owners.
> Why has the silicone become yellow? This is directly related to the technology used in neutral cure silicones. All neutral cure silicones will yellow due to oxidation of one of the raw materials. Removing and replacing the neutral cure silicone with another neutral cure silicone will not solve the problem. The best alternative is to consider using an acetic cure silicone, which will not yellow. It's important to note though, an acetic cure product can affect substrates like natural stones and reactive metals.

Comment: I would give it a good 72 hours before spraying stuff onto silicone. Removing them to re-do it is VERY time consuming.

Answer (score -1):

I tried everything to change my clear silicone back, I have just tried purple shampoo and it worked a treat! Purple cancels out the yellow, I hope this helps some one

Comment: Care to expand on this some? What, exactly, is "purple shampoo"?